# C++ parameterized header inclusion

Tags: c++, header-files

I'm working on an image processing project, and have created many libraries for different feature extraction methods. I have also another library that uses one of these libraries.

I don't want to include all of them, so I would like to selectively include libraries based on parameters defined by a config file. The config file stores the parameter and its value as shown below:

> lib: "a"

Is it possible to selectively include "library a" by reading the parameters in from this config file?

Comment: Yes, but it's system dependent, and usually only works for shared libraries. For Windows read about [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and related functions, on POSIX systems (like Linux and OSX) read about [`dlopen(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html).

Comment: By "include libraries", do you mean (A) optionally link to `something.lib` when compiling, or (B) optionally include `something.h` somewhere in the source code? Or perhaps both? It's *possible* to do either, but I think that we need some clarification about *why* you want to do this (i.e. what are you trying to achieve?) before we can give an answer, because I have a suspicion that this might be an example of the [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: I'm working on an image processing project and I created many libraries for different feature extraction methods. I have also another library that uses one of these libraries. I dont want to include all of them.

Comment: I think that it should be possible to use [pkg-config](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/) to determine which libs and `#defines` should be set up, and then use preprocessor directives to only `#include` the header files you need within your source code. Alternatively, you could do what Qt does and [run your own preprocessor on the source code files before compiling](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html) - although I'm not sure why you couldn't simply use DLLs to load the features you need into your program "on the fly", rather than trying to deal with things at the compiler stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include conditionals in compilation time with #ifdef #ifndef #endif directives

```
#define TypeA
#define TypeB


#ifdef TypeA
#include <lib.h>
#endif

#ifdef TypeB
#include <stdio.h>
#endif
```